# Customize Shopify by integrating with a 3rd party gift card API

Tags: shopify

We are looking to integrate Shopify with a 3rd party gift card service.  We want users to be able to buy a gift card provided by the 3rd party, and then when checking out on Shopify, to be able to use that gift card to pay for the purchase.

The 3rd party gift card has APIs we can use.

How could we do this with Shopify?

Comment: What research have you done on the subject? What have you already tried? Please explain what you have already researched/tried and exactly where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Have been researching the Shopify API here (https://help.shopify.com/api), and am stuck on how to adjust the balance due on an Order.  For example, ff an Order's balance due is $30, how can I lower it by $20 assuming I can deduct that amount from a gift card (using the external API), and then pay the remaining $10 using a credit card with Shopify.

Comment: You should skip trying to roll your own Gift Cards and just use the ones built into Shopify... save yourself headaches.

Comment: The reason we want to use 3rd party Gift Card, is because we have a physical store as well, and need to redeem those gift cards there.

Comment: Maybe have the user put the gift card in, in the inline cart/cart page and calculate the new value ahead of time using cart scripts. Just an idea to look at. https://help.shopify.com/manual/apps/apps-by-shopify/script-editor/examples

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need to build an Private Shopify App.

Using Shopify API you take the gift card details on the CART PAGE (not checkout unless you are a plus store)... the app will contact the Gift Card service, then if all goes well create an order in the admin section via Shopify API.

This can be 'marked as paid' and there relevant details added to a note in the newly created order.

As we would be skipping the checkout process, if your shipping out physical goods you'd need to collect the shipping address somehow.

Cost wise, its not going to be cheap but its more then do-able...