# Integrating Shopify and third-party gift-card system

Tags: shopify

### Background

I am working with a retailer who has a store on Shopify.  The store is not
on Shopify Plus.

The retailer has gift cards from a company other than Shopify.  Each gift
card has a number on it that uniquely identifies the card.  Associated with
the cards is a HTTP API, available to authenticated users, which can be used
to get or change the balance on a card.

### Requirement

The retailer wants to allow customers to use these cards when ordering from
his Shopify store.

### Ideal UI

From the user-interface point of view, the ideal would probably be something
like the following.  We would add an input field to the Shopify payment
form, near the input field that has the placeholder "Gift card or discount
code".  This new input field would be for the third-party gift-card number.

Suppose a customer had a gift card and entered its number into this input
field.  Some custom software would check whether the gift-card number was
valid and the gift-card had funds.  If either check failed, an error message
would appear in the form.

If both checks succeeded, the form would show success (perhaps by putting a
green check mark) next to the input field.  Then it would adjust the balance
to be paid by the customer.  For example, if the customer was ordering $300
worth of shoes, and tendered a gift card holding $50, then the $300 would be
adjusted to $250.

When the customer pressed the button to place the order, Shopify would debit
$250 from his credit or debit card, and some custom software would debit $50
from his gift card.  It's probably acceptable for this custom software to
run after a delay of 5 seconds or so.  (For example, it might be triggered
by a webhook.)

### Discussion

I've been looking for a way to do the above.  The really hard part is to
adjust $300 to $250 (not just in the form, but when Shopify actually charges
the customer).  I have considered the following, singly and in combination:

1. Changing the Liquid templates.
2. Putting some custom JavaScript in the Shopify pages.
3. Writing an app that uses the Shopify Storefront API.

(3) seems the most promising, but it's not easy to see how to do in a "surgical"
way so that I only replace one screen.
I don't want to have to reimplement an entire Shopify store using the Storefront API.

### Alternative UI

If you can think of an alternative UI that would achieve the same thing,
please feel free to propose it.

### Similar question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406130/customize-shopify-by-integrating-with-a-3rd-party-gift-card-api),
including the questioner's two comments, describes a situation
identical to mine.
However, the only answer (if I understand it correctly) is unacceptable to me.

### Ruled-out alternative

I proposed a web service to turn these third-party gift cards into Shopify
discount codes.  That idea was rejected by the retailer, because he already
uses Shopify discount codes, and Shopify's form only allows a single
discount code.

Comment: How are you planning to include JS in checkout if you are not on Shopify Plus store ?

Comment: I didn't know about that restriction.  I was not "planning to include JS in checkout"; I was deliberately open-ended about technologies.  But I must admit that, if I can't have JS in the checkout screen, the task seems a lot harder.

Comment: Seems difficult without Shopify Plus. May be you can try forcing user to go to Cart page before going to checkout. On cart page, create gift card field and then create a custom checkout with discounted price using storefront API and update the checkout url on cart page.

Comment: Is there a standard way to "update the checkout url on cart page".  The URL doesn't seem to be in the DOM (I've checked with the browser's Developer Tools).

Comment: Standard way ? No. Mostly it uses a form with action as "/cart" that Shopify redirects to Checkout on submit. If you are building for a specific client, you will have to handle it mostly using JS and will need to handle may details.

Comment: OK, I may be able to make that work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Actually, just thought of a question.  You suggested that I "create a custom checkout with discounted price using storefront API".  How does this "custom checkout" know the contents of the cart?  The cart appears to have an ID, but how do I transmit that ID to the "custom checkout"?

Comment: You would have to pass this information to your external API. You may use Shopify AJAX API to fetch current items of cart. Then add additional data like you Gift Card code etc. Then your custom API should return a Checkout URL.

Comment: Ah -- I didn't know about the Ajax API.  Now I see that I can use [GET /cart.js](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/cart#get-cart-js) to get the contents of the cart.  Thanks again for your help.